# exiftool.exe считать и записать данные в один проход в одном JPG файле

Tags: metadata, exif

подскажите конструкцию, как за один запуск exiftool.exe считать -CreateDate 1.jpg и сразу записать в File Modification Date/Time и в File Creation Date/Time в этом же файле 1.jpg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

exiftool.exe -P "-filecreatedate<datetimeoriginal" "-filemodifydate<datetimeoriginal" "1.JPG"